# JS: Why .value works in one case but it doesn´t in the other?

Tags: javascript, variables

I´ve got this working code:

**HTML**

```
Aumentar un <input id="porcentaje">% 
<input type="button" id="aumentar" value="Aumentar" onclick="calcular()">
<br>Monto: <input id="campo">
<br> If you insert a number into the "campo" input it should be aumented 
<br>by the same aumont that says the "porcentaje" input.
```

**JS**

```
function calcular() {
var original = document.getElementById('campo');
var aumento = document.getElementById('porcentaje').value;
original.value = original.value*aumento/100;
}
```

What I don´t understand is why this JS code works, and this one doesn´t:

```
function calcular() {
var original = document.getElementById('campo').value;
var aumento = document.getElementById('porcentaje').value;
original = original*aumento/100;
}
```

In other words, why I can use *var original = document.getElementById('campo');* but it doesn´t work with *var original = document.getElementById('campo')**.value**;* ?
But it does work with *var aumento = document.getElementById('porcentaje')**.value**;*.

I´m starting to learn about JS, and that difference I can´t understand.
In both cases I´m trying to reach the input value, but in one case it does work (var aumento) and in the other it doesn´t (var original).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because

```
var original = document.getElementById('campo');
```

gets you the reference to the DOM-Element of your input field. It's actually an object which can be manipulated afterwards. Whereas

```
var original = document.getElementById('campo').value;
```

gets you only the value which has no connection/binding to the input field anymore.